# MySql Matching id defined data with data from different rows

Tags: mysql

I'm taking Database Management course this semester and I'm working on one of assigned problems we got. We are supposed to create a database and give mysql statements for actions described.

The action that issues me is described like this:

Get the numbers of students who have the same sex and live in the same town as student 20.

I tried using inner join but I got errors which confuse me. I also tried matching but since there is no data stated, that didn't work either.
Here is my code.

```
create table student (nr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, town TEXT, birthdate 
    INTEGER, sex INTEGER, sname TEXT, ssurname TEXT);

create table lecturer (lnr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, lname TEXT, lsurname TEXT);

create table course (cnr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cname TEXT, lnr INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_clnr (lnr)
    REFERENCES lecturer (lnr) );

create table enrolledin (nr INTEGER, cnr INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_nr (nr)
    REFERENCES student (nr),

    FOREIGN KEY fk_cnr (cnr)
    REFERENCES course (cnr) );

create table exam (lnr INTEGER, cnr INTEGER, nr INTEGER, note TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_enr (nr)
    REFERENCES student (nr),

    FOREIGN KEY fk_ecnr (cnr)
    REFERENCES course (cnr), 

    FOREIGN KEY fk_elnr (lnr)
    REFERENCES lecturer (lnr) );

select nr, sex, town 
FROM student 
WHERE student AS S INNER JOIN matches M ON 
    S.sex = M.sex AND S.town = M.town WHEN nr = 20;
```

Comment: There is no keyword called 'when' in mysql database. "as student 20" does that mean you have to check the student with id 20 ?

Comment: Yes, I need to check for students who live in the same town and are of the same gender as student 20.

Comment: In that case, you should alter your query like, 
"WHERE student AS S INNER JOIN matches M ON 
    S.sex = M.sex AND S.town = M.town AND S.nr = 20; "

Comment: I tried your recommendation and now I'm getting syntax error. Is it possible for this to be written on the other way and the server is not recognizing this one?

Comment: What's the error? post the query you have modified

Comment: Oh!!!! There is a bigger mistake. You're applying the where condition even before the join. It should be,

select nr, sex, town 
FROM student AS S INNER JOIN matches M ON 
    S.sex = M.sex AND S.town = M.town WHERE nr = 20;

Comment: Silly me! I reset it and check this:
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 57: Table 'test.matches' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get the numbers of students who have the same sex and live in the same town as student 20

You should resolve this by a subselect. I dont understand why you use a join. All information are in student aviable.

So lets start:

First you need sex of student with nr 20:

```
SELECT sex FROM student WHERE nr = 20;
```

Than you need town of student with nr 20:

```
SELECT town FROM student WHERE nr = 20;
```

Now you need the count of students:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student;
```

At least you put everything together:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student
WHERE sex = (
    SELECT sex FROM student WHERE nr = 20
)
AND town LIKE (
    SELECT town FROM student WHERE nr = 20
);
```